Is it possible for an apex test to read from a static file
I need to write a test which handles very specific text and with multiline strings not really possible in APEX without contatenating manually each line, I would like to read this text directly from a file.
This will also help ensure that problematic encodings etc are preserved in the file and are part of the test passing or failing.
Is this possible? If so how do I read in this file both locally and on the cloud (in salesforce) when the test runs? I have heard about static resources but I can't find a beginner example of how to create and use one based on the logical starting point of having a local file (e.g. ./data/sample.txt for example) that you want to use.
Thanks.

To read a static resource, query it as a normal record:
StaticResource resource = [SELECT Body FROM StaticResource WHERE Name = 'something'];

Static resources are not subject to Isolation of Test Data from Organization Data in Unit Tests, so you can read the file without SeeAllData=true.
To read the file locally, you'd place it in your project's staticresources directory (e.g. force-app/main/default/staticresources/mytextfile.txt), although remember that Apex always runs on the server. See the StaticResource Metadata API documentation for more information on how static resources work in a project.
If this is a ZIP file, use the new Compression Namespace, although please note that, at the time of this answer, it is a Developer Preview and cannot be used in production.
Note to future viewers: Please edit or comment on this answer when this feature is Generally Available.
